# Starting Pharo with extra memory on OS X

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am running an expensive analysis and my Pharo image raises a Low Memory error.

I know there was a way of starting the Cog VM with extra memory but can't find it now. Does anybody know how to do that on a Mac?

Comment: This is definitely not professional server etc and also it is about a programming tool

Answer (score 3):

Oki, seems that I've found the answer myself. For the version of VM that I have I can run:

```
croquet -m 2000M
```

to run the image with 2G of memory.

Comment: Note that this fixes the heap size. Typically, the heap grows dynamically.